# Cant show related variable in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have trouble with showing related variable in laravel blade

```
public function GetAll()
{
 $news=DB::table('news')->get();
 return View('index',['news'=>$news]);
}
```

In View:

```
@foreach($news as $new)
 ...
        <a href="#">{{$new->comments()->count()}} Comments</a>
 ...
@endforeach
```

Its also doesnt work for any variables of object **but working good for first item**:

```
public function Count()
{
   $news=News::find(1);
  echo $news->comments()->count();
 }
```

Comment: It works good for first item because you use ORM (the "good" way), whereas when using the DB::table thing you are not getting objects but arrays. So use @Alex solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function GetAll()
{
$news = News::with('comments')->get();
 return View('index',['news'=>$news]);
}
```

Use ORM instead of DB.